# What are the network limits on each Heroku Dyno?

Tags: heroku

Using NodeJS, I am downloading and serving files to the user. Locally, this is done quickly (within a second or two), whereas on heroku, it takes up to 15 seconds for the file. Is there any way to increase this speed or view any specific limitations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not any specific per-second limits, but there's a 2TB soft cap per month (see [Limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits)). Note that if you're on the "free tier", your app can [sleep](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping). If this happens, it will take several seconds to "wake up." This might be what you're experiencing. The Hobby tier is about $5 a month, and prevents this from happening. You should get a much better experience if you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your help